# How to copy title and URL in bookmarklet

Tags: bookmarklet

[This links](http://computers.findincity.net/view/635399295212048058509784/how-do-i-copy-a-tabs-title-in-chrome) tell me how to create a bookmarklet for copying a tab’s title.

```
javascript:var%20title=document.title;if(title){var%20re=/(\|/|:|*|?|%22|<|>||)/gi;title=title.replace(re,'');void(prompt('Page%20Title',%20title));}
```

I want to copy both the URL and the title in the bookmarklet—how can I do it? I don't want an add-on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about bookmarklets are no longer on-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
javascript:title=document.URL + ' ' + document.title;if(title){void(prompt('Page Title',title));}
```